# Why is a TypeScript record assignable to a partial object with clearly different types?

Tags: typescript, typechecking

Consider the following program. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHgLhgJQKagE4BMA80MCWYA5gDQz5HEB8MAvDAN4wBmIISARAEYCGGnGAF8A3AChQkWAE8kzPgC8A-EjABXALbdUGGAB8YasFlQsiqLMPrwRMAPR2YAFWkAHVAGVghV7CwhUCDAAclhQDVcAG14iIA).

```js
const x: Record<string, string> = { foo: "bar" };
const y: { baz?: number | undefined } = x; // TypeScript doesn't complain
```

In the above example, I would have expected TypeScript to complain that `string` is not assignable to `number | undefined`. However, the above code type checks. Why?

Comment: `baz` is an optional property, and is missing in `x`. Had it not been optional, one could expect a complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is a structurally typed language, ie if two types have a similar structure they are assignable to each other.

```
// Example 1 - with no Excess property check (Because of implicit narrow type Record<string, string>)

const x: Record<string, string> = { foo: "bar" };

const y: { baz?: number } = x

// Example 2 - with Excess property check

const y1: { baz?: number } = { foo: 'bar' } // Error


// Also to prove Record<string,string> is assignable to { [k: string]: any }

type Assignable = Record<string, string> extends { [k: string]: any  } ? true: false // true
```

[Code Plyaground](https://tsplay.dev/WYkKxN)

Here when you do `x: Record<string, string>` it basically means `x: { [k: string]: string }` which is wider type than the actual `{ foo: "bar" }`

And for explicitly annotated types, [Excess property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) checks are not done, meaning we can supply additional props to it along with the required prop that is `baz`.

But since `baz` is partial and not required any other excess props can be added to it and `baz` will be inferred as undefined. hence typescript doesn't complain

To prove my point we can check that
`Record<string, string> extends { baz? :number } ? true: false` will be `true`

However if we directly try to assign an object literal type of the same Record type, typescript will complain as now the excess property check does happen.

> Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments.
> If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error.

**Side Note:**

`Record<string, string>` is not the preferred type for this scenario.
The idiomatic way of doing that is to use an index signature like `{ [k: string]: string }`

Because given `x: Record<string, string>`, `x.foo` will apparently be a string at compile-time, but in actuality is likely to be `string | undefined.`
This is a gap in how `--strictNullChecks` works